# In Firestore how to make Data structure and how to query them

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Now I'm developing the app in Firestore which can share photos in group.
Teach me how to make data structure.
I know only the data structure by using users and photos.

- Photos

  - photo-1

    - owner_id
    - url
  - photo-2

    - owner_id
    - url
- Users

  - user-1

    - user_id
    - user_name
  - user-2

    - user_id
    - user_name

When I want to query photo which match userId

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Photos")
    .whereField("owner_id", isEqualTo: userId)
```

these above can show us.

I have questions.
If I want to add groups who can see shared images,
How should I make data the structure and the query.
This function I want is like Google docs.
It can share only users permitted. So I think that is used by group function.

Please teach me the data structure and query.

Comment: You should check this useful document explaining a detailed implementation solution to  this scenario: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Answer (score 1):

The Photo document can have an array of allowed user ids (or users).
The following approach worked in my test environment.
Within the PhotosViewModel, we have got a fetchPermittedPhotos function, it handles that the current user just gets the photos he got permission to see.

## Models

#### User

In this example we take the uid from the current user which has been logged in by the firebase authentication (***Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid***).
The getCurrentUser function searches for a document with a specific document id, here it is using again the uid of the current user. That means, it is necessary that a (new) users id is identical to the uid. It is similar to the permission handling when fetching photos. The array contains a list of uids which get taken from ***Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid***.
If you don't want that, you have to adjust your code accordingly.

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {

    var id: String?
    var name: String

    init(name: String, id: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    init?(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        let data = document.data()
        let name = data!["name"] as? String ?? ""

        id = document.documentID
        self.name = name
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }
}
```

extension User: Comparable {

```
static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

static func < (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}
```

}

#### Photo

```
struct Photo: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String?
    var ownerUid: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var permittedUids: [String]
    
    init(ownerUid: String, imageUrl: String, permittedUids: [String], id: String = UUID().uuidString) {
        self.id = id
        self.ownerUid = ownerUid
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.permittedUids = permittedUids
    }
    
    init?(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        let data = document.data()
        let ownerUid = data!["ownerUid"] as? String ?? ""
        let imageUrl = data!["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        let permittedUids = data!["permittedUids"] as? [String] ?? []
        
        id = document.documentID
        self.ownerUid = ownerUid
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.permittedUids = permittedUids
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case ownerUid
        case imageUrl
        case permittedUids
    }
}

extension Photo: Comparable {
    
    static func == (lhs: Photo, rhs: Photo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: Photo, rhs: Photo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ownerUid < rhs.ownerUid
    }
}
```

## ViewModels

#### UsersViewModel

```
class UsersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var user: User?
    
    func fetchCurrentUser(_ completion: @escaping (Bool, String) ->Void) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(false, "Could not find firebase uid")
            return
        }
        
        let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(uid)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                self.user = User(document: document)
                completion(true, "User set up from Firestore db")
            } else {
                completion(false, "User document not found")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### PhotosViewModel

```
class PhotosViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    
    @Published var allphotos = [Photo]()
    @Published var permittedphotos = [Photo]()
    
    func addNewPhoto(photo: Photo, completion: @escaping (Bool, String)->Void) {
        do {
            try db.collection("photos").document(photo.id!).setData(from: photo) { _ in
                completion(true, "Photo added to Firestore")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing photo to Firestore: \(error)")
            completion(false, "Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllPhotos(_ completion: @escaping (Bool, String) ->Void) {
        self.allphotos.removeAll()
        db.collection("photos").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                completion(true, "No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.allphotos = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Photo in
                return Photo(document: queryDocumentSnapshot)!
            }
            completion(true, "Data fetched")
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPermittedPhotos(_ completion: @escaping (Bool, String) ->Void) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(false, "Could not find firebase uid")
            return
        }
        
        self.permittedphotos.removeAll()
        db.collection("photos").whereField("permittedUids", arrayContains: uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                completion(true, "No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.permittedphotos = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Photo in
                return Photo(document: queryDocumentSnapshot)!
            }
            completion(true, "Data fetched")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sebastian. Thank you for answering and writing code. You are so kind. 
Do you mean photos have array for users, right? 
I wii make reference. 
I have another question. Should I separate User and Photo in top level data? Or subcollection. 
What situation should I use subcollection on. 
I think 1:n relation can be top level or subcollection.
For example if user have payment data, it should be subcollection. cause in secure point.
What do you think of that?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, in my proposed approach, photos have an array of uids of users that are allowed to see the photos. When the user sends a fetch command to the Firestore db, the app takes the uid from the currently logged in user. The fetch command only get the documents from the "photos" collection, which contain the uid in the allowed uids array.

Comment: If photos or users is a sub-collection of the other one depends on your needs in your app and how the logic to fetch data is setup. I am not to detailed involved into your app, but I can imagine both, a sub-collection of photos within your users or two individual collections.

Comment: Since Firestore works different to (e.g.) Oracle SQL and instead of specific requested data (fields) you always get the entire documents, you definitely should split your user data in public data and private date. Otherwise, if all (public and private) data are in one document, all users that are download the user data of a foreign user are also getting the sensitive data. Even if your app doesn't show it directly, it is a security issue.

Comment: Hi, Sebastian. Thank you for supporting me. I have one question. If certain user belong to different groups and she/he have role property, can it be a bug? Role property is user access range(e.g)owner,user.
I think  when one user belong A group and has owner role, she/he also belong B group and has just user role. How should I make difference. My imagination is to join different rooms. So should I create another model like group? 
Please share your knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Adding to that,
If photos have role property which have array dictionary [{uid: "owner"},{"john":"user"}], when owner changes any photo's role he/she belongs to, all photos will be  overwritten. This means so cost. Cause firesore'price is to read and to write.
When I make another group model, it can be more manageable. What do you think of that?